# When should my friend file income tax?

Tags: income-tax, india, self-employment

My friend's income in the period apr 1, 2020 - mar 31, 2021 will be around rs. 875,000 (eight lakh seventy five thousand) only. He is a self employed business professional in information technology segment.

My friend is a resident of India.

1. When should my friend file income tax returns? before mar 31, 2021
   or before dec 31, 2021?
2. Does he need to file advance income tax? if yes, when?
3. If no deduction is applied, what will be the income tax?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

This should help: https://taxguru.in/income-tax/taxation-small-business-india.html

I googled "india small business when do you file taxes".

Comment: We want answer posts to actually answer the question in the text of the answer post, not simply point the OP to another page where they might find the answer.  Regardless, I'm not sure that that page contains the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica if I'd posted that as a comment, I'd have been bashed for answering in the comment section.

Comment: Yes, participation on this site requires a little more effort than just "I googled this for you, here is the link."

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I would have posted it as a comment but had recently been bashed for answering in the comments.

Comment: I agree, posting this answer in the comments would also have been a mistake.  But perhaps you are missing my point in my first comment.  The information in the link may or may not contain the answer to the OP's question.  If it does, all you need to do is find the answer, then post it here in text as a part of your answer.  If you can't find the answer there, then perhaps this should just be deleted.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I never wanted it to be an answer, but was trying to help point him in the right direction.